# AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation does not appear in Resource types pane of the CloudFormation Designer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In CloudFormation it's possible to create a resource of type AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation

As an example, here's a snippet where I've done exactly that in YAML.

```
Resources:    
  mySubnetRouteTableAssociation:
     Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
     Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref paramSubnetId
      RouteTableId: !Ref paramRouteTableId
```

I have to concede that in my CloudFormation journey I "got right into it" without really using the drop-and-drag aspect of the CloudFormation Designer (which the documentation calls the Resource types Pane). I now find myself in a position where I'm using the Resource types pane, and find theres no SubnetRouteTableAssociation resource.

I have considered a couple of possibilities, but they all seem unlikely.

1. It's somewhere else (not under EC2), and despite looking through umpteen times I can't find it.
2. AWS overlooked adding it.
3. It's been given a different name.
4. Some other good reason that I can't comprehend just yet.
5. It's expected to use another resource type that is "overloaded" to stand-in for this resource.

So in summary, can anyone shine some light on why the resource AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation is listed in the Resource types pane of the CloudFormation Designer ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide an update and how I have dealt with this in case others in the future have the same question.

The simple answer appears to be that the SubnetRouteTableAssociation does not exist within the Resource Types Pane. This does not mean that you can't have one because you can still create the resource manually within the template (writing the code directly).

This behaviour does appear at first to be a little inconsisent. One might argue that an association between two entities is not an actual AWS infrastructure object in itself and therefore is not deserving of a widget in the Designer Pane.

However, there is another similar resource type that behaves slightly differently - AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation

This resource also does not have an entry in the Resource Types Pane yet when you create it - it does get created within the Designer Pane, but not as a regular looking resource, but rather as a dependency (arrow). It's very easy to overlook but if you 'mouseover' the dependency arrow, the resource name appears.

So what is the difference ? Why does SubnetRouteTableAssociation not get any representation in the Designer Pane whilst SubnetNetworkAclAssociation does (even thought that representation is merely an arrow ?

My conclusion is because one requires a resource dependency (for resource creation purposes) whilst the other does not. I would prefer that every possible CFN resource is available in the Resource Pane. I hope this explanation/conclusion helps.